# How to create a link to a pdf with special characters in its name?

Tags: org-mode, org-link

I'm working in Linux under org-mode and trying to create a link inside an *.org file and this form works:

`[[shell:okular /home/quora/myfile.pdf][title]]`

Problem is, for pdf filenames like `my file[2nd ed.].pdf`. Tries like these didn't work:

`[[shell:okular /home/quora/my file[2nd ed.].pdf][title]]`
`[[shell:okular "/home/quora/my\ file\[2nd ed.\].pdf"][title]]`
`[[shell:okular '/home/quora/my\ file\[2nd ed.\].pdf'][title]]`
`[[shell:okular /home/quora/my\ file\[2nd ed.\].pdf][title]]`

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to escape the space as well, but the following works for me:

```org
[[shell: xpdf /tmp/files/1991_TOCS_synch\[2nd\ ed.\].pdf][foo]]
```

Or you can quote the path, but AFAICT, the square brackets need to be escaped in this case as well:

```org
[[shell: xpdf '/tmp/files/1991_TOCS_synch\[2nd ed.\].pdf'][foo]]
```

That indicates that Org mode parses them and gets confused if they are not escaped (it does not recognize a link at all). OTOH, Org mode does not care about the space but the shell does.